# How to extract multiple fields with specific character lengths in Bash?

Tags: bash

I have a file (test.csv) with a few fields and what I wanted is the Title and Path with 10 character for the title and remove a few levels from the path. What have done is use the awk command to pick two fields:

```
$ awk -F "," '{print substr($4, 1, 10)","$6}' test.csv [1]
```

The three levels in the path need to be removed are not always the same. It can be `/article/17/1/` or this `/open-organization/17/1` so I can't use the substr for field $6.

Here the result I have:

```
Title,Path
Be the ope,/article/17/1/be-open-source-supply-chain
Developing,/open-organization/17/1/developing-open-leaders
```

Wanted result would be:

```
Title,Path
Be the ope,be-open-source-supply-chain
Developing,developing-open-leaders
```

The title is ok with 10 characters but I still need to remove 3 levels off the path.

I could use the cut command:

```
cut -d'/' -f5- to remove the "/.../17/1/"
```

But not sure how this can be piped to the [1]

I tried to use a for loop to get the title and the path one by one by but I have difficulty in getting the awk command to run one line at time.

I have spent hours on this with no luck. Any help would be appreciated.

Dummy Data for testing:

### test.csv

Post date,Content type,Author,Title,Comment count,Path,Tags,Word count

31 Jan 2017,Article,Scott Nesbitt,Book review: Ours to Hack and to Own,0,/article/17/1/review-book-ours-to-hack-and-own,Books,660
31 Jan 2017,Article,Jason Baker,5 new guides for working with OpenStack,2,/article/17/1/openstack-tutorials,"OpenStack, How-tos and tutorials",419

Comment: use `awk`s `split` and get first and 5th field

Comment: And post the sample file. Testing with unwanted result is not very productive and will lead to massive amount of follow-up questions.

Comment: Thanks for the tip on the split option. To split this into 5 parts, I would need to set 2 delimiters. Pipelining with awk '{split($0,a,",|/"); print a[1]; print a[5]}' doesn't work yet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can replace the string by using regex.

```
stringZ="Be the ope,/article/17/1/be-open-source-supply-chain"

sed -E "s/((\\/\\w+){3}\\/)//" <<< $stringZ
```

note that you need to use `-i` if you are going to give file as input to sed

Comment: This is great. I can pipe this to the awk command and it works! Prior to this, I have also tried Kamil's idea although I lost the header text Path after running this: awk -F "," '{print substr($4, 1, 10)","$6}' test.csv |awk -F ",|/" '{print $1", "$6}'. Thank you all!

Comment: I just noticed the the sed removes levels like this "/article/17/1/" but NOT this "/open-organization/17/1". I guess I won't figure it out why until I understand the regex used here.